# Why is df.loc['row', 'col'] the same as df['col'].loc['row']?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I can see theyre both referencing the same cell/value, but why does `df['col'].loc[row]` even work? I learned to use loc as df.loc[rowname,colname].

I saw it in a list comprehension:

```
fb['Direction'] = [1 if fb['PriceDiff'].loc[ei] > 0 else 0 for ei in fb.index ]
```

So why would you write:

```
fb['PriceDiff'].loc[ei]
```

and not:

```
fb.loc[ei, 'PriceDiff']
```

Is there any reason/advantage?

Thanks!

Comment: Note btw, that neither `[1 if fb['PriceDiff'].loc[ei] > 0 else 0 for ei in fb.index ]` nor `[1 if fb.loc[ei, 'PriceDiff'] > 0 else 0 for ei in fb.index ]` is a good idea anyway. Such a computation is a negation of what dataframes are for. If you want to use list comprehension, then use good old python dict instead of dataframe, that would be faster. The whole point of dataframe is to work on whole columns (or even whole dataframes), not values by values. For example, `fb['direction'] = (fb['PriceDiff']>0)*1`

Comment: Note that this is not aesthetics. If dataframe are big, we are talking factor 5000 in runtime here (I've just measured with a 1000000 long dataframe. The compound list method is 5000 times slower than the vectorized version)

Comment: I didnt know that, and will take it into account from now on. I like your suggestion. Thanks.